# 5-20V VBUS sensing with 5V only IC

Tags: voltage, transistors, usb, usb-c

I am designing a board with a [FT230 USB to UART IC](https://datasheet.octopart.com/FT230XS-R-FTDI-datasheet-41192799.pdf). In battery powered applications, one of its GPIO can serve as a VBUS sensing pin.

However, the FT230X was designed for 5V applications, before the era of USB Power Delivery. In my case I'm expecting voltages of up to 20V on VBUS, but with a VIH of 2.0V on the GPIO, I don't see any voltage divider that would produce a logic high voltage on the entire 5-20V range.

So I'm looking for a small circuit that would produce a logic high whenever the VBUS is above 4.5V, as illustrated below.

[image]

Comment: Use a comparator.

Comment: Are you sure the FT230X will do power delivery negotiation for you?

Comment: *I'm expecting voltages of up to 20V on VBUS* I'm **not** since the FT230 doesn't support that and cannot do the PD negotiation to **request** more than 5 V from the USB host so the USB host will never deliver more than 5 V. This is exactly why the negotiation is needed, to prevent the USB host from providing more than 5 V to devices that cannot support it. See it as a "secret handshake", only if you know it, you get 20 V. The FT230 doesn't know the secret handshake.

Comment: Guys, I'm very well aware of the ways Power Delivery works. What I voluntary omitted because I thought it was not relevant to the issue is that Power Delivery would be done by another chip not shown the image above.

Comment: @Andyaka, thank you for that suggestion. I'm going to explore the option. For now I've found the [TLV1805](https://www.ti.com/product/TLV1805) which seems interesting for its high voltage tolerance and push-pull output.

Comment: You don't need a high voltage comparator. Make a voltage compare with the potted down voltage and run the comparator from 5 volts.

Comment: also you can use a resistor+zener to clamp down to something manageable (like 6 volt) and work from that. Or even use a zener to *subtract* the 5V, depending on the precision you need

Comment: The diagram shows 4-pin regular USB connector. This one will never deliver anything above 5.5V with USB PD. However, if you will use QC, than it might be different. I feel that this question is not up to complexity of the task with elevated VBUS voltages.

Comment: I faced the same problem. What is your final decision?

Comment: @ymakux I believe I never finished this design, so no definitive answer. I didn't like the approach of the zener diode as it would dissipate power unnecessarily. I still think I would purse the option of using a comparator.